# Update A Profile Picture In Django ImageField : Dynamic Method Used In Django Admin

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, imagefield

My Application has a system where user can upload his profile pic. I created this feature later so used the foreignkey method

this is the model

```
 class Profile_Pic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='', null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userPic')
    profile_pic = StdImageField(upload_to='photos', default='', blank=True, )
```

and the html page

```
{% extends 'datas/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    <h1 class="text-center" style="color: white">Add Profile Picture</h1>
    <br><br>

     <div class= "col-md-6.offset-md-3">

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable" role="alert">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                        <small><sup>x</sup></small>
                    </button>
            <p>Data Error, Please Check Again.....</p>
                    {% for field in form %}
                      {% if field.errors %}
                        {{ field.errors }}
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
        </div>

    {% endif %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">

    </form>

     </div>

{% endblock %}
```

the view

```
@login_required
def profile_pic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Photo(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your Profile Picture Has Been Updated Successfully')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = Photo()
    return render(request, 'datas/user_image.html', {'form': form})
```

and finally the form

```
class Photo(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile_Pic
        fields = ['profile_pic']

        widgets = {
            'Add Profile Pic': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

[image: Upload Page]
[image: Admin Upload Model]

Now when we upload from the admin site,the system automatically deletes the previous photo on the same model, but when the same is done from the user interface,a new model is saved every time,so is there a way where I can update the model that is already been created and so I can update the picture?

Thank You.....

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you only have create function; you do not have update function.

in views.py, make a update view. You might need to tweak a bit.

```
@login_required
def update_profile_pic(request, pk):
    print('under update_profile_pic view')

    profile_pic = get_object_or_404(Profile_Pic, pk=pk) # get instance

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Photo(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile_pic) #note instance

        if form.is_valid():
            
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your Profile Picture Has Been Updated Successfully')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = Photo(instance=profile_pic) # note instance
    return render(request, 'datas/user_image.html', {'form': form})
```

Make sure to update your urls.py